# trying to write to python .txt file

Tags: python

I am a new programmer, so be easy on me, I have watched a video on youtube, and understand most of it ( or so I thought).

I get an error when I try to run

```
import logging
import csv

Date = input ('what date was it?')  
fish = input ('what type of fish did you catch?')  
fly = input ('what fly did you catch the fish on?')  
water = input ('what was the water conditions?') 

fileName = 'fish.txt'
WRITE = 'w'  # write rebuilds the file, so nothing is in the file!
READ ='r'
APPEND = 'a'
ReadWrite = 'w+'

file = open('fileName', 'a') 
file.write (Date + "\n")  
file.write (fish + "\n") 
file.write (fly + "\n") 
file.write (water + "\n")  

allFileContents = fileName.read()
print (allFileContents)

file.close()
```

does anything jump out at you that might be wrong?

Comment: Something might if I knew the error.  Python gives the traceback for a very good reason: it is *verrrrrrry* helpful in debugging.

Comment: You are confusing strings, variable names, and file objects. I suggest you continue studying - asking a question here should be your last resort, not your first, as SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: see, I have done the research, asked a question that got me no where in another forum, and got a BS answer there as well.  I have gone to youtube, and watched a 13 hour video, and have tried different things all day with no real outcome.  I even through a windows 10 VM on my Mac, so I could use Visual studio, and try it there.  

I would think that someone with your stature might just ask me first before you decide I haven't done anything.

Comment: BTW, the answer I was provided earlier about the allFileContents was correct I came back to thank whoever wrote that up for me.  
thank you!

Comment: I will not be come back here due to seeing how members are treated..thank you for your help whoever it was, and thank you Tigerhawk for allowing me to see what type of people are on this board.

Comment: The difference between objects and their reference names is one of the first things you will learn in any programming course. That might be what's giving the impression (both here and on the forum you tried) that you haven't done any research. Either the video you watched was of incredibly low quality, or you didn't study the concepts thoroughly enough.

Comment: @JeffBrown Sorry to hear that your experience here was soured. The community here is very helpful. If I may play the diplomat here for a moment. Typically when a question comes around that more-or-less asks "why is this not working", some frustrations get let out due to the frequency they come around. Sometimes conclusions are jumped to assuming that people are looking for code grabs and have not put in that much effort. This is not to take away by the work that you did.

Comment: Jeff, try here: [code school](https://www.codeschool.com/learn/python) they have a free python class or two that are easy to follow and are taught competently.

Comment: @JeffBrown I think a better approach to have introduced you to Stack Overflow, would have been to direct you to these helper docs to better guide on how to ask effective questions. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The most important thing that you left out is the error traceback.  I would have been very happy to help if I knew what the error was, but I wasn't willing to guess.  I'm not as much of a downer as some people, so I didn't downvote, but that is a likely reason for others.  As I mentioned in my first comment, the traceback is there for a very good reason.  I'm very sorry that you had a bad experience.  idjaw went to greater lengths to help you than most other people would.  When you ask a question, it's us helping you.  Giving the proper information is your responsibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually opening your file here:

```
allFileContents = fileName.read()
```

`fileName` is simply your file name as a string, you want to use `open`:

```
allFileContents = open(fileName).read()
```

Furthermore, you are actually trying to write to a filename called `fileName` here:

```
file = open('fileName', 'a')
```

But, I think you want to actually reference your variable you created, `fileName`. So, you want:

```
file = open(fileName, 'a')
```

Small comment about your code to help out.

Here, you seem to be creating variables holding the different modes when opening a file:

```
WRITE = 'w'  # write rebuilds the file, so nothing is in the file!
READ ='r'
APPEND = 'a'
ReadWrite = 'w+'
```

You don't use this in your code, and to be honest is really not helpful in general. You can just still to using these directly when you call your `open` methods. So you can make do without them.

Finally, you seem to have import statements that you are not using:

```
import logging
import csv
```

Typically, it's always best to avoid importing modules that you are not using. If you are going to use them in the *future*, it's best to get in to the habit to import them when you actually need them.

Comment: So far as I can tell from the code snippet, both imports are unnecessary in this case. The write =, read =, append = also seem more like comments than useful code in this case.

Comment: @Lost I agree. I wanted to provide *immediate* fixes. But, yes, there are other comments that could be made to improve the code.

Comment: Concur, you probably fixed what was causing his error -- mostly working off of the final question which was "anything that might be wrong" but didn't want to put up a duplicate answer

Comment: @Lost you inspired me a bit. I made a comment about those unneeded variables.

Comment: yeah, I was using them as a memory holder (mine goes out sometimes), so I put those there as I increase the code.  I plan on taking this and trying to create a loop for info on the fish that was caught till the user is finished.  This is just me trying to learn something new, and wanting to expand my limited knowledge.

Comment: @JeffBrown If you are writing notes for yourself inside your code, consider making it a comment. It will avoid the risk of having it affecting your code.

Comment: @JeffBrown Also, I updated my answer again to include another tidbit of info along the lines of the modules you are importing. Good luck with your studies.